# vector base derived class

Tags: vector, interface, stl, derived-class, base-class

I am not able to call negedge of all the subscribers who register for clock, all subscribers also derive from ClkIf

```
class ClkAdapter : public ClkIf
{
    virtual void negedge() 
    {
        for(std::list<ClkIf*>::iterator it = clk_list.begin(); it != clk_list.end(); it++)
            (it->negedge)();
    }

    virtual void posedge() 
    { clk_cnt++; }

    void registerForClock(ClkIf* module)
    {   clk_list.push_back(module); }

    std::list<ClkIf*> clk_list;        
    unsigned long long clk_cnt;
};
```

error: request for member 'negedge' in '* it.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> with _Tp = ClkIf*', which is of non-class type 'ClkIf*'
Error in negedge function, What is wrong in this code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of pointers, so the list iterator would work *similarly* to a double pointer (that is, `ClkIf**`). Thus, you would have to call `(*it)->negedge()` within the loop. The `(*it)` fetchs the current `ClkIf*` element first, and then the -> operator calls the function on *that* value.

Comment: Works now, was shameful of me